# Redirecting https to http in .htacces with some exceptions

Tags: .htaccess, magento, redirect, https

I'm using a magento website and all pages on the site are accessible through http and https and that might be causing duplicate content issues with google. I need the proper coding for redirecting in htacces all the https pages to http with the exception of these pages:

- https://www.example.com/checkout/onepage/
- /customer/account/
- /checkout/multishipping/login/
- /wishlist/
- /index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/

(Not sure if you need a seperate exception rule for these or it's included in the previous ones)

- /checkout/multishipping/addresses/
- /wishlist/index/index/
- /customer/account/login/
- /checkout/onepage/success

Would greatly appreciate if anyone can help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

# From https to http
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/checkout/onepage/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/customer/account/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/checkout/multishipping/login/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wishlist/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# From http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/checkout/onepage/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/customer/account/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/checkout/multishipping/login/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wishlist/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I tried it and all the regular pages on the site if you try it with https it would redirect properly to http, but when I tried to access any of the pages that need to be secure for example the wishlist page I saw the page change a second to https and then it redirected to the home page. Can it be because those pages that need to be secure were already redirected to https before I put in this code. Or maybe there is some kind of conflict in the htacces coding? I can upload the .htacces file if you want to see it.